# Presentation order of inner self join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

If I have a table as follows:

```
+------+-------+   
| sno  | cno   |  
+------+-------+  
|    1 | CS112 |  
|    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS114 |  
|    2 | CS112 |  
|    3 | CS112 |  
|    3 | CS114 |  
|    4 | CS112 |  
|    4 | CS113 |  
|    5 | CS113 |  
|    6 | CS113 |  
|    6 | CS114 |  
+------+-------+
```

If I do an inner self-join on `sno` I would expect to see the rows in the following order:

```
+------+-------+------+-------+  
| sno  | cno   | sno  | cno   |  
+------+-------+------+-------+  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS112 |  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS114 |  
|    1 | CS113 |    1 | CS112 |  
|    1 | CS113 |    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS113 |    1 | CS114 |  
etc
+------+-------+------+-------+
```

But the order is

```
+------+-------+------+-------+  
| sno  | cno   | sno  | cno   |  
+------+-------+------+-------+  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS112 |   
|    1 | CS113 |    1 | CS112 |  
|    1 | CS114 |    1 | CS112 |  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS113 |    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS114 |    1 | CS113 |  
|    1 | CS112 |    1 | CS114 |  
etc
+------+-------+------+-------+
```

I.e. I expected to see each row in the left side to be repeated for each row in the ride. The opposite happens. I.e. it seems to take all rows and match it to the first in the right side of the join.
Why is the order like this?

Answer (score 2):

You should have no expectation on the order of results in a query, unless you use an `order by` clause (or in MySQL, a `group by` clause).

Unfortunately, I haven't found the reference in the MySQL documentation that *explicitly* says this.  The closest is this quote [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html):

> You may have noticed in the preceding examples that the result rows
>   are displayed in no particular order. It is often easier to examine
>   query output when the rows are sorted in some meaningful way. To sort
>   a result, use an ORDER BY clause.

The ANSI standard does specify, though, that query results (and tables) are unordered except when an `order by` clause is specified.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but conceptually I had in mind a linear scan of the table in the left and a parallel scan of the table in the right. It seems to do it the other way round. I was wondering why.

Comment: @Cratylus . . . SQL is, for the most part, a *descriptive* language.  That is, is specifies the desired results, not how to obtain them.  The SQL engine is a black box that returns those results.  In this case, the engine decided to flip the two sides of the join, relative to what you would expect.  To understand this and other optimization techniques, you need to study the details of the specific database.

Comment: Is it my idea or don't most textbooks imply the "ordering" I expected?

Comment: @Cratylus . . . I can't speak for other authors.  Everything that I've written about SQL emphasizes that tables and queries produce *unordered* result sets.  It is easy to confuse understanding the algorithms with the results of a query.  Unfortunately, you are not going to learn about hash joins, merge joins, parallel hash joins, and other join techniques in an introductory textbook on SQL (not that these are necessarily used in MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

Think of tables as sets of records. I say "sets" because that's usually a valid word in a far cousin of SQL called [Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). And, of course, there is no order in sets.

Once you add an `order by` clause, then you'll get the results in the specified order:

```
select t1.sno, t1.cno, t2.sno, t2.cno from t t1
join t t2 on t1.sno = t2.sno
order by t1.sno, t2.sno, t1.cno, t2.cno
```